# compatibility cturtle - electric

Tags: ros, cturtle, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm a new ros user. I'm working on a project written in ROS cturtle's version. I'm having a lot of problems infact cturtle is supported on ubuntu 10.10 (the last) and i cannot upgrade my pc with an upgraded OS.
I've tried to import the project in Ros electric but i've too much compilation errors (i think that are libs problems).

There is a way to install cturtle on new OS? Or,
There is a way to get compatibility between the two versions?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11458/compatibility-cturtle---electric/) by [pacifica](https://answers.ros.org/users/1187/pacifica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-10**:
Can you be a little more specific about what you're trying to do?  Both electric and cturtle work on Maverick.  Are you trying to get cturtle to run on a newer version of Ubuntu?  The list of supported distros is in REP 3 http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-07**:
can you edit your post and add a sample (not the whole list!) of the errors you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree that upgrading to Electric is probably best. While there *are* differences, compatibility between C-turtle and Electric is quite good.

I know of no central list of all the changes introduced in each distribution. Given the federated nature of ROS development, that would not be practical. Instead, each stack publishes a ChangeList for every version released. If an API has changed, refer to the change list for the containing stack.

For example, camera driver changes are listed here:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_drivers/ChangeList.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try installing cturtle from source, but it might be easier, especially towards the future, to switch to electric. This should be possible unless some important API has changed dramatically. If there are errors that you can't resolve yourself, you can get help here.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1